# How to resize KivyMD Accordion

Tags: material-design, kivy, kivy-language

**The issue:**

I'm using KivyMD Accordion, it's height takes up most of the UI space & shrinks the other widgets that should be contained within each accordion item as shown in the image below.

How do I fix/set the height of the Accordion to take up lesser space? Appreciate any inputs!

Code snippet:

```
     MDAccordionItem:
        title: "HOME" 
        icon: 'key'
        GridLayout: # Root Layout of the screen
            rows:4

            ActionBar:
                pos_hint: {'top':1}
                ActionView:
                    use_separator: True
                    ActionPrevious:
                        title: 'Employee Info' 
                        with_previous: False

#-----------------CODE HERE FOR 2ND ACCORDION ITEM-------------------
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `MDAccordionSubItem:` before `GridLayout:`

## Snippet

```
 MDAccordionItem:
    title: "HOME" 
    icon: 'key'

    MDAccordionSubItem:
        GridLayout: # Root Layout of the screen
            rows:4

            ActionBar:
                pos_hint: {'top':1}
                ActionView:
                    use_separator: True
                    ActionPrevious:
                        title: 'Employee Info' #Nucleic Acid Extraction
                        with_previous: False
```

## Output

[image: Img01]